# How to create / update customer information using REST API?

Tags: magento2, customer, rest-api

How to create/update customer using REST API in magento2?

I searched a lot on google but not getting any solution for this.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create new customer

```
$userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "admin123");
$ch = curl_init("http://magento213/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);


$customerData = [
    'customer' => [
        "email" => "user@example.com",
        "firstname" => "John",
        "lastname" => "Doe",
        "storeId" => 1,
        "websiteId" => 1
    ],
    "password" => "Demo1234"
];

$ch = curl_init("http://magento213/index.php/rest/V1/customers");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

//For update

```
$customerData = [
    'customer' => [
        'id' => 10,
        "email" => "user@example.com",
        "firstname" => "John2",
        "lastname" => "Doe2",
        "storeId" => 1,
        "websiteId" => 1
    ],
    "password" => "Demo1234"
];

$ch = curl_init("http://magento213/index.php/rest/V1/customers/10");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

[API List](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/list.html)

Comment: http://magento213, should be your url. It's tested M2.1.3.

Comment: I used this code for magnto-2 but password is not updating.

Comment: @SohelRana Why do I need to put in alll those fields that are not being updated for an update? (I asked this as its own question here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258640/update-customerdata-with-rest-api]

Comment: @SohelRana Can we create user using magento 2 own endpoints just passing some username and password. Like we get customer using API.