# Could not update password using customer ID in Magento-2 REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, curl

I am facing one issue. I am trying to update the customer password using Magento-2 `REST API` but the password could not update. I am explaining my code below.

```
$adminUrl='http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
            $ch = curl_init();
            $data = array("username" => "abc@gmail.com", "password" => "abc@123.");

            $data_string = json_encode($data);                       
            $ch = curl_init($adminUrl); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
                'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
            );       
            $token = curl_exec($ch);
            $token=  json_decode($token);
            $randno=rand();
            $email=$randno."@email.com";
            $customerData = [
                'customer' => [
                    "id" => 25,
                    "email" => 'subhra@email.com',
                    "firstname" => $randno,
                    "lastname" => $randno,
                    "storeId" => 1,
                    "websiteId" => 1,
                     "customAttributes" => [
                ],

                "addresses" => [

                ]
                ],
                "password" => 'sbha123@'
            ];
            $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $token"); 
            $requestUrl='http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/25';

            //echo $requestUrl;exit;
            $ch = curl_init();
            $ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $token));   
            $result = curl_exec($ch); 

            $result = json_decode($result, 1);
```

Here I am trying update customer record with `password` but when I am doing the authentication using below code it could not happen.

```
$adminUrl1='http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token';
    $ch1 = curl_init();
    $data1 = array("username" => 'subhra@email.com', "password" => 'sbha123@');

    $data_string1 = json_encode($data1);                       
    $ch1 = curl_init($adminUrl1); 
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string1);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string1))                                                                       
    );       
    $token1 = curl_exec($ch1);
    echo $token1;
```

The above code is throwing the below error.

```
{"message":"You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.","trace":"#0 [internal function]:
```

Means the password could not update because I can get expected output using the previous password. Here I need to update also the password.

Comment: is this your real admin username `abc@gmail.com`?

Comment: No I have changed here and gave just an example.

Comment: @kunj  I was just following this `https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154363/how-to-create-update-customer-information-using-rest-api` link to update the record.

Comment: I mean username should be `admin` not Email Id like this `array("username" => "admin", "password" => "admin@1234");`

Comment: @kunj  sorry that is the username I have given. Its correct.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be that you are not logging incorrectly in your admin account.

For updating customer password you can use `/V1/customers/me/password` it routes to the method `changePasswordById` in class `vendor/magento/module-customer/Api/AccountManagementInterface.php`

Comment: I am using the  `postman and REST API` to update the customer record with `password`.

Comment: @satya I have not used Postman, so not sure about that, I assume article https://medium.com/@yvoronoy/how-to-generate-schema-for-magento2-api-and-import-to-postman-c08a0318af98 may be helpful to you.

Comment: Here I put some static value for to easy understand but in my end I am passing `password` dynamically from using `postman` means I am using one php file where those above code are present getting password value from postman post method.

Comment: I tried by taking the help of this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154363/how-to-create-update-customer-information-using-rest-api link.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 :: Customer reset password [Forgot password]**

> webapi.xml

```
<route url="/V1/customers/password" method="PUT">
    <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface" method="initiatePasswordReset"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

> url :: action - PUT

---

```
http://<magento.host>/index.php/rest/V1/customers/password
```

> Body > raw > JSON(application/json)

---

```
{
"email": "aditya@test.com",
"template": "email_reset",
"websiteId": 1
}
```

> Output :: Customer receive reset password url in mail on registred
>   mail id. Need to pass email template - email_reset

---

**Method 2 :: Here how it goes for Change password if you know the old One**

> webapi.xml

```
<route url="/V1/customers/me/password" method="PUT">
    <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface" method="changePasswordById"/>
    <resources>
    <resource ref="self"/>
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
```

> This is a API call from the Magento file, just for you to understand
>   how it works.

**url**

---

```
http://<magento.host>/rest/V1/customers/me/password?customerId=160
```

> URL action - **PUT**

```
it must be PUT method in POSTMAN
```

> Headers

---

```
Authorization  Bearer <Token>
Content-Type   application/json
```

> Body > raw > JSON(application/json)

---

{
    "currentPassword": "aditya@123",
    "newPassword": "admin@456"
}

> Pass data like this, In json format

**Output**
It will change customer password, need to pass current and new password in body.

Comment: You mean if one will forget his/her old password can not it reset ?

Comment: of-cause it can

Comment: Then how because as per your answer it need old password with new one.

Comment: Yeah, my answer is for change customer password, not for forgot password. Yes but you can achieve it using /V1/customers/password API

Comment: on /V1/customers/{customerId}/password/resetLinkToken/{resetPasswordLinkToken} to make sure the token/user is legit

Comment: Here I think one link will sent to to reset the password and if its correct then using `post man` my requirement is I only want to reset  the password. In my case all data are updating without that password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82114/discussion-between-satya-and-aditya-shah).

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's working for me.

```
$jsoneEconoded= '{"customer_id": 3,"currentPassword": "kunj123","newPassword": "kunj@123"}';
$ch = curl_init($url."V1/customers/me/password");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsoneEconoded);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

//echo $requestUrl;exit;
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),1);
if(strlen(curl_error($ch)) < 1)
{
    print_r($result);
    exit;
}
else{
    if((is_array($result))&&(isset($result['message']))){
        echo $result['message'];
        exit;
    }
}
```

you can learn more from here : https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_22.html

Comment: Ok its change password but I want to implement the forgot password like functionality.