# Update Customer data with REST API

Tags: magento2, customer, rest-api

SO I am not sure if this is a bug or not, when using the API to update a product in magento 2.3.0 a PUT request like such:

```
curl -X PUT "https://example.com/index.php/rest/all/V1/products/24-MB01" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" -d "{ \"product\": { \"visibility\": 3 }}"
```

updates the visibility for the product with that SKU (as one would expect) however when i try to make a simillar update to a customer with a PUT request like this:

```
curl -X PUT "https://example.com/index.php/rest/all/V1/customers/8" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" -d "{ \"customer\": { \"middlename\": \"string\" }}"
```

I get a 400 error with `"message": "The customer email is missing. Enter and try again."` the API to update only works if i add all of the required data like this:

```
curl -X PUT "https://example.com/index.php/rest/all/V1/customers/8" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" -d "{ \"customer\": { \"id\": \"8\", \"firstname\": \"Jon\", \"lastname\": \"Smith\", \"email\": \"Jjsmith@gmail.com\", \"middlename\": \"jac\", \"store_id\": 1, \"website_id\": 1 }}"
```

if I leave any of these values out i get an error with the exception of `id` which if left out creates a new record or throws an error if the email already exists (despite the `id` being specified at the end of the URL) also when `id` is passed in with the data that IDs record is updated even if it is not the `id` at the end of the URL

This does not seem to be the way the API should operate any help or explanation of whats going on would be appreciated.

Comment: PUT is used for updating. POST for creating. that's restful

Comment: there is no POST request for the customer API in swagger

Comment: swagger only shows you the endpoint you can use with your resources

Comment: and yes, there is one: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/etc/webapi.xml#L125

Answer (score 1):

I created an issue and a PR for thiswill see if magento accepts it...

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/21236

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21237

Comment: At what point does Magneto have to stop calling itself open source?

Answer (score 0):

"/V1/customers/:customerId" PUT is used for updating.

"/V1/customers" POST for creating.

You always have to provide the full-customer object

Comment: My question is why do you need to provide the full customer object? why doesn't the ID in the URL suffice as it does for the product, also what is the point of the ID in the URL as it is ignored and the one in the object is used regardless of which ID is in the URL

Comment: What is the proper channel to ask them?

Comment: i'd recommend slack

Comment: @YehudaSchwartz some entities are updated using replace strategy (like Customer), while the others - using patch strategy (like Products). There is inconsistency in this area mostly due to historical reasons: lack of standardization and parallel development by independent teams.